# Do I need to add gatsby-plugin-react-i18next language query to every page?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am using the gatsby-plugin-react-i18next for translating a site. My question is, do I have to add the language query posted below to every page I intend to translate? Is there a better way?

```
// /pages/index.js
}
export const query = graphql`
  query($language: String!) {
    locales: allLocale(filter: { language: { eq: $language } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          ns
          data
          language
        }
      }
    }
  }

`;
```

I looked at the example provided on github and the query appear in every page.
https://github.com/microapps/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/tree/master/example/src/pages